# SpringDoc (spring boot) utf-8 json header response for documentation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using springdoc (springdoc-openapi-ui) for rest documentation for a kotlin spring boot application (Gradle build) and I want to know if there's a way to setup the response header content type encoding to utf-8. The defautlt returned content type is :
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question related to springdoc-openapi.

You should have a look at your spring-boot application encoding setting.

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server-properties